# Making a bracket on each item in the enumerate environment(true/false problem)

Tags: horizontal-alignment, enumerate

I want to make something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,enumerate}
\newcounter{num}
\newcommand{\exam}[1]
{\bigskip\bigskip\noindent\refstepcounter{num}\textbf{Example \arabic{num})} #1\par\noindent}

\begin{document}

%
\exam{Read the following sentences and write 'O' or 'X' in each bracket}
\begin{enumerate}[(1)]
\item
If \(x\) is real, then \(\sqrt{(x-1)^2}=|x-1|\).
\(\quad\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\quad\)[\qquad]
\item
If \(y\) is real, then \(\sqrt{y^2}=y\).
\(\quad\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\quad\)[\qquad]
\item
If \(t\le0\), then \(\sqrt t^2\neq t\).
\(\quad\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\quad\)[\qquad]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

with the outcome like this. [image: this]

I manually typed the commands like `\(\cdots\)` iteratively, but I'd rather do it automatically so that the brackets are generated and aligned to the very right side for each `item` in the `enumerate` package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\dotfill`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,enumerate}
\newcounter{num}
\newcommand{\exam}[1]
{\bigskip\bigskip\noindent\refstepcounter{num}\textbf{Example \arabic{num})} #1\par\noindent}

\begin{document}

%
\exam{Read the following sentences and write 'O' or 'X' in each bracket}
\begin{enumerate}[(1)]
\item
If \(x\) is real, then \(\sqrt{(x-1)^2}=|x-1|\).
\dotfill[\qquad]
\item
If \(y\) is real, then \(\sqrt{y^2}=y\).
\dotfill[\qquad]
\item
If \(t\le0\), then \(\sqrt t^2\neq t\).
\dotfill[\qquad]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with `\cdot`s. (Big thanks to @Fractal for pinging me!)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,enumerate}
\newcounter{num}
\newcommand{\exam}[1]
{\bigskip\bigskip\noindent\refstepcounter{num}\textbf{Example \arabic{num})} #1\par\noindent}

\begin{document}

%
\exam{Read the following sentences and write 'O' or 'X' in each bracket}
\begin{enumerate}[(1)]
\item
If \(x\) is real, then \(\sqrt{(x-1)^2}=|x-1|\).
{\leaders\hbox{$\,\cdot$}\hfill}[\qquad]
\item
If \(y\) is real, then \(\sqrt{y^2}=y\).
{\leaders\hbox{$\,\cdot$}\hfill}[\qquad]
\item
If \(t\le0\), then \(\sqrt t^2\neq t\).
{\leaders\hbox{$\,\cdot$}\hfill}[\qquad]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,enumerate}
\newcounter{num}
\newcommand{\exam}[1]
{\bigskip\bigskip\noindent\refstepcounter{num}\textbf{Example \arabic{num})} #1\par\noindent}

\newcommand{\Cdotfill}{\leaders\hbox{$\,\cdot$}\hfill}
\begin{document}

%
\exam{Read the following sentences and write 'O' or 'X' in each bracket}
\begin{enumerate}[(1)]
\item
If \(x\) is real, then \(\sqrt{(x-1)^2}=|x-1|\).
\Cdotfill[\qquad]
\item
If \(y\) is real, then \(\sqrt{y^2}=y\).
\Cdotfill[\qquad]
\item
If \(t\le0\), then \(\sqrt t^2\neq t\).
\Cdotfill[\qquad]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice :) but I think you might need to raise the dots a bit (the OP wants to align those dots at the middle of the line.

Comment: @Fractal Thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh, I haven’t heard of \leaders before :) I was expecting something like \cdotfill :)

Comment: Btw ‘leaders’ is really a weird name IMHO

Comment: @Fractal I agree. But what can be do? There are many other examples, for instance, as a cat, I also do not like how "cat code" is used. ;-)

Comment: You are a genius. Thanks!

Comment: @Fractal -- "leaders" is the traditional typesetting term.  It's been in use since long before TeX existed.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks! (BTW, cats were already known to the old Egyptians but still "cat code" gets used in an inappropriate way. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmQhF.png) is how cat code looks like. ;-)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for the information. Still can’t figure out the relationship between leadership and typesetting though.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat -- Gee, I would have expected longer whiskers!

Comment: @Fractal -- Not "leadership" per se.  It's a line that leads the eye in a particular direction or to a destination.